# How to stop page reload on server side call pagination ?php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

I am implementing pagination where on click i change the style from list view to grid but when i click the next page button or link it is actually redirects me back to again list view button again

```
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";
```

now i want to keep my style same as it was if i have clicked grid so on next page click it remain a grid not turn to list as page load again fetch new record it change my style

```
   $(document).ready(function () {    
  var elem=$('#container ul');      
    $('#viewcontrols a').on('click',function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('gridview')) {
        elem.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
            $('#viewcontrols').removeClass('view-controls-list').addClass('view-controls-grid');
            //$('#viewcontrols .gridview').addClass('active');
            $('#viewcontrols .listview').removeClass('active');
            elem.fadeIn(1000);
        });                     
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('listview')) {
        elem.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
            $('#viewcontrols').removeClass('view-controls-grid').addClass('view-controls-list');
            $('#viewcontrols .gridview').removeClass('active');
            //$('#viewcontrols .listview').addClass('active');
            elem.fadeIn(1000);
            });                                 
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

so is there any why like i declare a such a variable that donot destroy even on page load and manage style or how to do that ?

```
 var elem=$('#container ul');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the selected style in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). On page load you can load the style from the localStorage again.

Comment: if yes you are right but how to maintain tab like if i am on 3rd tab on refresh remain in 3rd in same way for all browsers

Comment: @scott the page I linked has a browser compatibility table further down the page. I am not sure what you mean by maintaining tabs, do you mean the currently selected page?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<li id="pagination_link"><a href= . . . ></li>
```

Then in JS, something like this:

```
$('#pagination_link').on('click', 'a href', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or if I remember correctly:

```
$('#pagination_link').on('click', 'a href', function(e){
  return false;
});
```

Should stop the link redirecting. You just need to override the default behavior of a href.

Comment: the problem is to maintain the grid if choosen or list on click new page

Comment: to maintain viewcontrol state

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in your question to say, as it'll depend on how the next N records are being retrieved and rendered in. In my mind, reloading the whole page from a JS pagination doesn't make sense- you'd usually only want to eval the table/ grid, which would be styled to the CSS currently on the page. The problem here is the use of href- ideally, you want to prevent its default behavior, then retrieve/ load in the next records using an AJAX call or something. Are you using a framework like Rails to deal with retrieving data from the DB?